# how to change upload directory from ACF Pro Extend

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to understand how to change and add new upload path to this plugin...
https://www.acf-extended.com/features/hooks-helpers/fields#upload-directory. Reading their stuff but it seems incomplete to my understanding. I also tried reading this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upload_dir/ which given from their support documentation. I tried doing the example but I can't figure out to make it to work.

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'property_directory');

function property_directory( $param ){
    $mydir = '/'.$property_name;

    $param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mydir;
    $param['url'] = $param['url'] . $mydir;

    return $param;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what the `$uploads` param returns when uploading to ACF imagery fields with the field name `property_gallery` using the `acfe/upload_dir` filter. See php example at end of question to show you working method.

```
Array
(
    [path] => /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/2022/09
    [url] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/09
    [subdir] => /2022/09
    [basedir] => /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
    [baseurl] => https://example.com/wp-content/uploads
    [error] => 
)
```

Here is example of how the [ACFE upload directory filter](https://www.acf-extended.com/features/hooks-helpers/fields#upload-directory) works...

```php
add_filter('acfe/upload_dir/name=property_gallery', 'property_directory', 10, 2);

function property_directory($uploads, $field) {

    // not sure how you will set your property name variable?
    //$mydir = '/properties/'.$property_name;

    // example property directory with child property name directory
    $mydir = '/properties/example-property-name';

    // update the path and url array values
    $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'] . $mydir;
    $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'] . $mydir;

    // return uploads ($param)
    return $uploads;

}
```

Here is the results below when uploading `test-image-upload.jpg` to ACF image field name `property_gallery`.

I have not tested this with an ACF gallery or file field, but I think the results should be the same using AFCE field name targeted filter...

[image]

---

Here is a tested solution below which adds uploaded images for 3 ACF property imagery fields to a `properties` sub directory in the uploads folder.

Each property uploads will be added to a sub directory in the `properties` directory. The sub directory name will be set with the property post `ID`.

> It will be safer to use the property post `ID` as the sub directory
> name because you will run into all sorts of issues if a property name
> is modified after initial draft or publishing.
>  The property post
> `ID` is a constant and will never change, so easier to use property
> post `ID` instead of naming the sub directory with property
> `post_name`.

Here are the 3 ACF property imagery fields which are assigned to the `property` post type...

[image]

Here is the PHP which goes in `functions.php` which saves any uploads added to the 3 ACF imagery fields, into a property post `ID` sub directory in the `wp-content/uploads/properties` directory...

```
// change our upload directory for acf property imagery fields
add_filter('acfe/upload_dir/name=property_image', 'property_directory', 10, 2);
add_filter('acfe/upload_dir/name=property_gallery', 'property_directory', 10, 2);
add_filter('acfe/upload_dir/name=property_file', 'property_directory', 10, 2);

// property imagery field filters directory function
function property_directory($uploads, $field) {

    // action and request vars
    $actions    = ['upload-attachment'];
    $request    = array_change_key_case($_REQUEST,CASE_LOWER);

    // are we where we want to be?
    if(!(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && in_array($_REQUEST['action'],$actions))) {

        // if not then return default uploads directory
        return $uploads;

    }

    // if request post id is set
    if(isset($request['post_id'])) {

        // setup our property post vars
        $property_id    = $request['post_id'];
        $property       = get_post($property_id);

        // if property var is WP_Post Object
        if($property instanceof WP_Post) {

            // property sub directory as property post id
            $property_dir = '/properties/' . $property_id;

            // update the path and url array values
            $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'] . $property_dir;
            $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'] . $property_dir;

        }

        // return uploads ($param)
        return $uploads;

    }

    // return uploads again no matches above
    return $uploads;

}
```

The result using the above `functions.php` code when uploading images and files to the property ACF imagery fields in the property post type...

[image]

> The above screenshot property post `ID` is `6215`

Here is how the above uploads are then saved to the `wp-content/uploads` directory...

[image]